# Best way to remove multiple if-else

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

So the similar type of questions are answered elsewhere but here I am expecting the best way to omit if else chain for the given situation.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
private ViewModel getViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
  String receiptType = receipt.type;

  if(receiptType.equals("HOTEL")) {
    return new HotelReceiptViewModel(receipt));
  } else if(receiptType.equals("CAR")) {
    return new CarReceiptViewModel(receipt));
  }
  .
  .
  .
  } else if(receiptType.equals("LUNCH")) {
    return new FoodReceiptViewModel(receipt));
  }
}
```

where all the view models extend a class called `ReceiptViewModel`. e.g.

```
public class HotelReceiptViewModel extends ReceiptViewModel implements ViewModel {
    public HotelReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
        super(receipt);
        this.receiptNumber = receipt.getDocumentNumber();
        this.receiptHeading = "HOTEL";
    }
}
```

There are currently 5 types of receipts and there will be 3-4 more types of receipts in future.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

1. Use of `HashMap`
2. Use of `Enum`
3. Use Strategy Pattern or Command Pattern
4. Use of Reflection

Let's see pros and cons of each approach

---

**1. Use of HashMap**

```
private ReceiptViewModel getViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
  Map<String, ReceiptViewModel> map = getViewModelsMap();

  String receiptType = receipt.type;
  ReceiptViewModel viewModel = map.get(receiptType);
  if(viewModel != null) {
    viewModel.setReceipt(receipt);
  }

  return viewModel;
}

private Map<String, ReceiptViewModel> getViewModelsMap() {
  Map<String, ReceiptViewModel> map = new HashMap<String, ReceiptViewModel>();
  map.add("HOTEL"), new HotelReceiptViewModel());
  map.add("CAR"), new CarReceiptViewModel());
  map.add("LUNCH"), new FoodReceiptViewModel());
}
```

and `ReceiptViewModel` classes will look like

```
public class HotelReceiptViewModel extends ReceiptViewModel implements ViewModel {
  public HotelReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
    super(receipt);
    this.receiptNumber = receipt.getDocumentNumber();
    this.receiptHeading = "HOTEL";
  }
}
```

*PROS*
Faster, Easier, Extensible.

*CONS*
`ReceiptViewModel` object does not require an object of `Receipt` type in the constructor. `Receipt` is rather set using a setter, where all the logic of initializing the `ReceiptViewModel` class will move now.

---

**2. Use of Enum**

```
private ReceiptViewModel getViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
  String receiptType = receipt.type;
  ReceiptViewModel viewModel = 
        ReceiptViewModels.valueOf(receiptType).getReceiptViewModel(receipt);

  return viewModel;
}
```

And Enum will look like

```
public enum ReceiptViewModels {
   HOTEL(
       ReceiptViewModel getReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
           return new HotelReceiptViewModel(receipt);
       }
    ),
   CAR(
       ReceiptViewModel getReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
           return new CarReceiptViewModel(receipt);
       }
    ),
    .
    .
    .
   LUNCH(
       ReceiptViewModel getReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
           return new FoodReceiptViewModel(receipt);
       }
    ),

    public abstract ReceiptViewModel getReceiptViewModel(Receipt receipt);
 }
```

*PROS*
Fast, Probably Easy.

*CONS*
Size of Enum will keep on increasing as the receipt types increase, resulting in non-maintainable code.

`ReceiptViewModels.valueOf(receiptType)` expects a known receipt type. If a new receipt type comes as a response from server, it will result in an `IllegalArgumentException`

---

**3. Use of Reflection**

```
Class<? extends ReceiptViewModel> viewModel = Class.
            forName(receiptType + name + "ReceiptViewModel").asSubclass(ReceiptViewModel.class);
        ReceiptViewModel receiptViewModel = viewModel .newInstance();
```

*CONS* 
1. Slower

2. Cannot be used when the class names are different. e.g. For LUNCH type the view model class name is FoodReceiptViewModel
3. Logic of getting values from receipt is moved to a setter instead of constructor as in case of HashMap

---

**4. Use of [Strategy Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) or [Template Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm)**

*PROS* Easy to understand and faster than Reflection

*CONS* Probably an overkill. A new class will be added for each type of receipt.

---

Considering all the above points, which would be the best approach for my use case to remove the multiple if-else blocks?

Comment: Strategy is the best with map in which key would be enum.

Comment: @SMA Would you recommend adding 9 classes for 9 types of receipts where all of them will have almost similar kind of code?

Comment: You're missing an option: a switch statement. But in any case, this is not a good question for StackOverflow as people can only give you their opinions. Please read the [help] for more information on asking good questions here. (You also haven't described your use-case in much detail, so how can anyone decide what could be good for your use-case)

Comment: Yes you should create 9 classes and use them as either a strategy (which i strongly recommend) or factory

Comment: Your map example is wrong. You should associate a factory function to each type, which knows how to instantiate the appropriate view model. That still allows to pass the receipt through the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a switch, unless there is a reason to use something more complex.

```
private ViewModel getViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
  switch(receipt.type) {
    case "HOTEL": return new HotelReceiptViewModel(receipt);
    case "CAR": return new CarReceiptViewModel(receipt);
    case "LUNCH": return new FoodReceiptViewModel(receipt);
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown receipt type " + receipt.type);
}
```

I would claim this is the best solution as it is the simplest which meets you needs.

Comment: That is pretty much equivalent to the enum solution.

Comment: @plalx except without defining a new class and with a lot less code.

Comment: It is also  coupling the ViewModel class to all its subclasses and it is not type-safe.

Comment: Ugh, this approach requires duplicating the type constant strings. A better, type safe and DRY solution would be to make the receipt type an enum.

Comment: @MickMnemonic agreed if these strings appear else where in the code.

Answer (score 2):

No behavior needed, no structure needed, no polymorphism needed,  so I don't see interest to use design patterns such as strategy or to use a map which brings nothing but complexity in the need you describe.
You want a very simple state machine. So, "if else if" or "switch" is perfect .
Maybe out of the subject but with a private method, the code is not unitary testable.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new abstract method into your `Receipt` class. Something like

```
public <T extends ReceiptViewModel> T createModel()
```

And then would create subclasses of the `Receipt` class where each `type` would correspond to one subclass. Then each subclass will implement his own version of `createModel` returning the correct subclass of `ReceiptViewModel`. Your initial code will be as simple as

```
private ViewModel getViewModel(Receipt receipt) {
  return receipt.createModel()
}
```

Comment: That would mix concerns. Receipt is a domain concern while a view model is a presentation concern.